# CpoException: Can not execute command 'cpoptimizer -angel'. Please check availability of required executable file

Tags: optimization, cplex, docplex, cp-optimizer

I have **CPLEX Optimization Studio** installed on my Ubuntu machine and I am using the `docplex` model module with success. Now I have to use **CpoModel** from `docplex.cp.model` and I have the error:

> CpoException: Can not execute command 'cpoptimizer -angel'. Please check availability of required executable file.

I have no idea what's going on. I cannot get support from **IBM** because I have student license.

Comment: FYI: to get support with Academic Initiative licenses and CP Optimizer you can use the official IBM forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002066). However, it is fine to ask questions here too.

Answer (score 6):

Please try the following as suggested [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/400597/cpoptimizer-on-docplex/):

```
CpoModel.solve(agent='local',
               execfile='COSHOME/cpoptimizer/bin/cpoptimizer')
```

Where `COSHOME` is the directory where CPLEX Optimization Studio is installed.

Alternately, you can create a file named `cpo_config.py` that looks like the following and include it in your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
context.solver.agent = 'local'
context.solver.local.execfile = 'full path of the cpoptimizer executable'
```

The advantage of the later is that it would apply to all of your docplex programs. See also the documentation on [configuring the local solving agent](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/cp/docplex.cp.config.py.html#configuration-of-the-local-solving-agent).

Comment: Thanks. I've also just got this working with `from docplex.cp.config import context\n,
    context.solver.agent = 'local'\n,
    context.solver.local.execfile = '/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cpoptimizer/bin/x86-64_linux/cpoptimizer'\n`